# How to repeat Select statements in a loop in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, plsql

I am reading a lot of stuff about repeating Select statements within a loop but I am having some difficulties as I have not found something clear till now. I want to execute some queries (Select queries) several times, like in a FOR loop. Can anyone help with some example please?

Comment: Please show an example of what you are trying to do.  THis is too vague.

Comment: Stop thinking in "loops" when it comes to relational databases. Think in sets instead. Most of the time people that ask "how to do a loop in SQL" are actually looking for a join. Therefor you should show us some sample data and the expected output from that sample data.

Comment: Yes I understand, as I said I am having difficulties with this. That is why I am asking for a small example that works because I am not able to run properly the examples that I am finding, just as the one that posted the answer below.

Comment: It would be much better if you showed us some sample data and the output you want from that instead of insisting to write a loop. I'm pretty sure we can come up with a better solution than a loop.

Comment: Thank you, I want to Select a row of a table that has a column date. I want to set the date to one week after the current in each iteration till the column date will be greater than today. I can not think of anything apart of the loop for this. Do you have another idea?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The basic structure of what you are asking can be seen below. 
Please provide more information for a more specific code sample.

```
DECLARE
  l_output NUMBER;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10 LOOP
    SELECT 1
    INTO l_output
    FROM dual;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result: ' || l_output);
  END LOOP;
END;
```

PS: If you need to enable output in SQL*Plus, you may need to run the command
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

#### *UPDATE*

To insert your results in another table:

```
DECLARE
-- Store the SELECT query in a cursor
  CURSOR l_cur IS SELECT SYSDATE DT FROM DUAL;  
--Create a variable that will hold each result from the cursor
  l_cur_rec l_cur%ROWTYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Open the Cursor so that we may retrieve results
  OPEN l_cur;  
  LOOP
    -- Get a result from the SELECT query and store it in the variable
    FETCH l_cur INTO l_cur_rec;
    -- EXIT the loop if there are no more results
    EXIT WHEN l_cur%NOTFOUND;
    -- INSERT INTO another table that has the same structure as your results
    INSERT INTO a_table VALUES l_cur_rec;        
  END LOOP;
  -- Close the cursor to release the memory
  CLOSE l_cur;
END;
```

To create a View of your results, see the example below:

```
CREATE VIEW scott.my_view AS 
  SELECT * FROM scott.emp;
```

To view your results using the view:

```
SELECT * FROM scott.my_view;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is pretty much what I want to achieve but I found this code even in other websites and this do not work. Can you give me an example that works please?

Comment: Sorry about that, please see my updated response. Is this what you need?

Comment: Yes thanks again, this works. One last question, hoping I am not bothering you. I want to get the output of the structure through a select statement or better I want to create a View in database that will be filled with results from the procedure. Can you help?

Comment: I have added some code in my response, does this resolve your problem?